# JPopupMenu Java

Tags: java

Estoy trabajando con un JPopupMenu en NetBeans, quiero que mi JPopupMenu se desaparezca inmediatamente el mouse se encuentre fuera de este, probé poniéndole un listener al JPopupMenu de tipo mouseExited, pero lo que pasa es que apenas el mouse se posa encima de un JMenuItem, que hace parte de este el listener se ejecuta haciendo que la ventana desaparesca. ¿Como puedo solucionarlo? ¿Hay alguna otra forma de hacer esto?

Comment: Esto tiene varios detalles. Probé haciendo una combinación de MouseListener para saber cuando entra el puntero y luego MouseMotionListener para saber la posición del mismo mientras se desplaza dentro del menu. Te sugiero extraer el ancho y alto del JPopUpMenu para establecer los limites. Pero el mayor problema son los JMenuItem ya que cuando entras el listener lo asocias como que salistes del JPopUpMenu. Hay que seguir investigando.

Comment: Gracias amigo, encontré ya una solución. Lo arregle creando una rutina apenas el JPopupMenu se vuelve visible, la cual esta revisando que la posicion del mouse no sea mayor a la posición del JPopupMenu + el tamaño, la rutina se destruye apenas el JPopupMenu desaparece.Comparto el código por si alguna persona puede llegar a necesitarlo

Comment: `rutina = new Timer(60, (ActionEvent e) -> {
            Point coorMouse = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
            Point coordenadasJPopupMenu = jPopupMenu1.getLocationOnScreen();
            if(coorMouse .x > coordenadasJPopupMenu.x+jPopupMenu1.getWidth() ||
               coorMouse .x < coordenadasJPopupMenu.x ||
               coorMouse .y > coordenadasJPopupMenu.y+jPopupMenu1.getHeight() ||
               coorMouse .y < coordenadasJPopupMenu.y){
                jPopupMenu1.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        rutina.start();`

Comment: Daniel coloca tu rutina como una respuesta y no como comentario

Answer (score 0):

La solución la encontré, creando una rutina la cual se instancia apenas el JPopupMenu se vuelve visible, esta estará revisando constantemente que la posicion del mouse no sea mayor a la posición del JPopupMenu + el tamaño, la rutina se destruye apenas el JPopupMenu desaparece.Comparto el código por si alguna persona puede llegar a necesitarlo.

```
    Point coordenadasMouseNow = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    Point coordenadasJTable = jTable1.getLocationOnScreen();
    if(coordenadasMouseNow.x > coordenadasJTable.x+jTable1.getWidth() ||
        coordenadasMouseNow.x < coordenadasJTable.x ||
        coordenadasMouseNow.y > coordenadasJTable.y+jTable1.getHeight() ||
        coordenadasMouseNow.y < coordenadasJTable.y){
        jPopupMenu1.setVisible(false);
        return;
    }
    rutina = new Timer(60, (ActionEvent e) -> {
        Point coordenadasMouse = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        Point coordenadasJPopupMenu = jPopupMenu1.getLocationOnScreen();
        if(coordenadasMouse.x > coordenadasJPopupMenu.x+jPopupMenu1.getWidth() ||
           coordenadasMouse.x < coordenadasJPopupMenu.x ||
           coordenadasMouse.y > coordenadasJPopupMenu.y+jPopupMenu1.getHeight() ||
           coordenadasMouse.y < coordenadasJPopupMenu.y){
            jPopupMenu1.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    rutina.start();
```